# Deleting Multiple Site Groups from a Site using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions

I'm looking to delete bulk (300+) Site groups (limited access users) that exist in a site. Powershell seems to be the fastest option, however I'm not great with it and I'm looking to have a script that doesnt delete all groups.

I want the Powershell script to delete all groups except for those which I specify... e.g. loop through all site groups and delete them all, except the groups I specify "My Group Name", "Restricted Readers", etc.

I found a sample script below where you have to specify which groups you want delete.. I want the opposite of this, where I can delete all groups except a set of groups with a certain name..

**Example script**

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://mysite"
$spGroups = $spWeb.SiteGroups

$groups = ("Group 1", "Group 2","Group 3","Group 4","Group 5","Group 6")

ForEach($group in $groups) {
   $spGroups.Remove($group)
}

$spWeb.Dispose()
```

*Edit: I want to delete the application of these groups to the site, e.g. what is achieved when you select the group and click "Remove User Permissions" in the UI*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to keep the groups and remove *Role Assignments*, right?

Try this one:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://server/sites/test
$keep = 'Group 1', 'Group 2'
$remove = $web.RoleAssignments | ? Member -NotIn $keep | % { $_.Member }
$remove | % { $web.RoleAssignments.Remove($_) }
```

Or a little longer version:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://server/sites/test
$keep = 'Group 1', 'Group 2'
$remove = $web.RoleAssignments | Where-Object { $_.Member -NotIn $keep } | ForEach-Object { $_.Member }
$remove | ForEach-Object { $web.RoleAssignments.Remove($_) }
```

For Office 365:

```
$siteUrl = 'https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test'
$keep = 'Group 1', 'Group 2'
Connect-SPOService -Url 'https://test-admin.sharepoint.com' #tenant admin URL
$site = Get-SPOSite $siteUrl
Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site | ? LoginName -NotIn $keep |
  % { Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site -Identity $_.LoginName -PermissionLevelsToRemove $_.Roles }
```

Comment: Also wanted to ask.. the above script will work fine with SP Online?

Comment: Also, is there a limit on the amount of groups that can have Role Assignments removed?  (e.g. when I tried from UI it failed to remove role assignments for > 100 groups)

Comment: I've added O365 version - it is quite different than on prem. I'm not aware of any limitations either in UI or scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://mysite"
$spGroups = $spWeb.SiteGroups

Write-Host "This site has" $spGroups.Count "groups"

$doNotDeleteGroupNames = ("Approvers", "Group 2","Group 3","Group 4","Group 5","Group 6")

$groups = $spGroups | ? {$_.Name -notin $doNotDeleteGroupNames}
Write-Host "Found" $groups.Count "groups which will be deleted:"

ForEach($group in $groups) {
   Write-Host "Deleting" $group.Name "..."
   $spGroups.Remove($group.Name)
}

$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: This will remove the groups. Expected result is the same as *Remove User Permissions* in UI, so only permissions should be removed.

Comment: ok, then i did not understand him correctly, your answer seems correct then

Comment: Thanks Nils, I was seeking for exact this powershell script!